# Array to string containing comma's - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Ok so I'm writing a script that includes whole sentences, but whole sentences can contain comma's.

Due to the way the script works the array has to be turned into a string at least once.
So when that happens the comma's start conflicting with each other once I split the string back into the original values.

I can't quite figure out how to fix this and i've been looking all over with no success so far.

I'm working with chrome plugins, this is a small example of what happens:

```
var Data = ["This is a normal string", "This string, will cause a conflict.", "This string should be normal"];

// The data gets sent to a background script, in string form and comes back as this
var Data = "This is a normal string, This string, will cause a conflict., This string should be normal";
Data = Data.split(",");

// Results in 4 positions instead of 3
Data = ["This is a normal string", "This string"," will cause a conflict.", "This string should be normal"];
```

Comment: You need to provide some examples and your current code. We can't deduce anything from what you've written so far.

Comment: So don't use commas as the join delimiter? .join(">>><<<")

Comment: Please explain in detail why your script does need a stringification of arrays of strings. Otherwise, just escape the commata, or use JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `.join()` on the array in order to convert it to a string yo ucan specify the delimiter.

For example:

```
["Hello,","World"].join("%%%"); // "Hello,%%%World"
```

You can then split it based on `"%%%"` (`.split("%%%")`) in order to break it apart again.

That said, if you want to apply an action to each element of an array (every line) you probably do not have to call `.join` and then `.split` it again. Instead, you can use array methods, for example:

```
 var asLower = ["Hello","World"].map(function(line){ return line.toLowerCase(); });
 // as Lower now contains the items in lower case
```

Alternatively, if your goal is serialization instead of processing - you should not "roll your own" serialization and use the built in `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` methods like h2oooooo suggested.

Comment: What if one of the sentences contains the phrase `%%%`?

Comment: @Bergi +1 Of course, you have to choose a delimiter you are certain that does not appear in the strings. That's a good thing to note, thanks. I've also clarified that this is usually not the prefered approach for solving what I believe the "Y" problem OP has (but I can't tell).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`JSON.stringify(array)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse(json)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to make sure that whatever array/object you enter will come back the exact same (and it also works with booleans, integers, floats, etc.):

```
var data = ["This is a normal string", "This string, will cause a conflict.", "This string should be normal"];

// The data gets sent to a background script, in string form and comes back as this
data = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(data);
// ["This is a normal string","This string, will cause a conflict.","This string should be normal"] 

data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data);
// ["This is a normal string", "This string, will cause a conflict.", "This string should be normal"]
```